# Div height follow smaller div height

Tags: html, css, css-position, css-tables

I have two divs, one beside the other. The left one will have a lot of content, so i want to put scrollbar on it. The right div will have less content so left div should follow height of right div.

Content of right div is dynamic so I can't set `max-height` of left div. I tried with `display:table-cell` but unsuccessfully.

```css
.container {
  display: table;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 30px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">CELL1: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus a facilis saepe. Commodi exercitationem, provident nemo ea distinctio dolor ullam ab facere blanditiis inventore debitis nobis vitae maxime suscipit accusantium.</div>
    <div class="cell">CELL2: lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/enco164/mk9ez2qn/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by wrapping the first cell (I call it with `first` class here) and calling it `absolute`.

```
<div class="cell first">
  <div>
  CELL1: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus a facilis saepe. Commodi exercitationem, provident nemo ea distinctio dolor ullam ab facere blanditiis inventore debitis nobis vitae maxime suscipit accusantium.
    </div>
</div>
```

and apply this:

```
.cell.first div{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

and `overflow-y: auto` for each `cell`.

Maybe you have to adjust the widths. See example below:

```css
.container {
  display: table;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 30px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.cell.first div{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell first">
      <div>
      CELL1: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus a facilis saepe. Commodi exercitationem, provident nemo ea distinctio dolor ullam ab facere blanditiis inventore debitis nobis vitae maxime suscipit accusantium.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">CELL2: lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Cheers! Let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this,

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
    <div class="cell-content">
    CELL1: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus a facilis saepe. Commodi exercitationem, provident nemo ea distinctio dolor ullam ab facere blanditiis inventore debitis nobis vitae maxime suscipit accusantium.
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
       <div class="cell-content">CELL2: lorem lorem lorem lorem </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  display: table;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 30px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
.cell-content{
  max-height:200px;  /* as per your requirement */
  overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: Content of right div is dynamic so I can't set max-height of left div. I updated my question.

Comment: So, do u want to have scroll bar after the 100% height of the window/document size ?